Ошибка связанная с "Authentication plugin 'mysql_native_password' cannot be loaded:"
я прохожу курс по С++ и на уроке на котором обьясняли как подключить mysql через mysql-connector к C++ при запуске программы мне выдало ошибку "Authentication plugin 'mysql_native_password' cannot be loaded:"
#include <iostream>

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

using namespace std;

const string SERVER = "tcp://localhost:3306";
const string USER = "root";
const string PASSWORD = "root";

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");
    
    sql::Driver* driver;
    sql::Connection* conn = nullptr;
    sql::Statement* stmt;

    try {
        driver = get_driver_instance(); //делает ссылку на sql коннектор c++
        conn = driver->connect(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD);
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException& ex) {
        if (conn != nullptr && !conn->isClosed()) 
            conn->close();
        cout << "Error connection.\n" << ex.what();
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    conn->close();

    return 0;
}


Крайне сильно прошу вашей помощи

MySQL 9.0 – it’s time to abandon the weak authentication method, https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/180498

Вы не писали версию MySQL, но предполагаю что 8.4+, в ней в стандартный пакет не включен плагин "MySQL Native Password" по умолчанию.
Почитайте тут, должно помочь.

5.7.24 вроде версия такая.Ввел разделе sql запрос:SELECT VERSION();
Версия коннектора : mysql-connector-c++-9.1.0
Версия MAMP 5.0.6

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
